# Quickest way to generate xmldocument object from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, file

whats the quickest way to generate an XmlDocument object from a file. Im working on the basis that i know my xml is well formed, and ideally im looking for a method that will allow me to simply pass in a string as my file location, and return a complete XmlDocument object.

Comment: XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument(); xDoc.Load("c:\\myXmlFile.xml");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um, [`XmlDocument.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx)?

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(filename);
```

On the other hand, if you're using .NET 3.5 or higher you should strongly *consider* moving to LINQ to XML and [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) instead:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
```

LINQ to XML is a much nicer XML API.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way would be:

```
string pathToXmlFile = //your path;
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(pathToXmlFile);
```